# Haskell how to terminate recursive call and avoid non-exhaustive patterns

Tags: haskell, io, pattern-matching

Working on terminal based app that uses a number of `putStr`/`getLine`'s for gathering user input. Would like to use the following function to shorten the tedious `putStr` `getLine` by feeding it a list of questions and returning the answers in a list (recursively). Although the `getLine`s terminate nicely, I cannot avoid the `non-exhaustive patterns` on the `putStr` side of things. 
This is not a duplicate. Multiple `getLine`'s can be done using `replicateM`, but it's the combination of questions/answers I am after.

```
(***) = hFlush stdout

questionnaire :: [String] -> IO [String]
questionnaire (x:xs) = do
    putStr x
    (***) 
    user <- getLine
    case user of 
        "" -> return []
        _  -> do
            nextUser <- questionnaire xs
            return (user : nextUser)
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`, it will list the patterns you did not cover.

Comment: Spoiler alert: what will `questionaire []` do?

Comment: You can use `mapM` here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not quite, if you want to preserve the `"" -> return []` behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need explicit recursion here, making it impossible to forget to define `questionaire` when its argument is an empty list.

```
questionaire :: [String] -> IO [String]
questionaire  = traverse getWithPrompt
  where getWithPrompt x = do
            putStr x
            (***)
            getLine
```

Example:

```
> users <- questionaire ["name? ", "name? ", "name? "]
name? alice
name? bob
name? charlie
> users
["alice","bob","charlie"]
```

---

`getWithPrompt` has type `String -> IO String`. `traverse` is a little like `map`, except where `map getWithPrompt prompts` would leave you with a value of type `[IO String]`, `traverse` combines the list of `IO` actions into a single `IO` action which executes each `IO` action and gathers their results into a single list.

---

As pointed out by Daniel Wagner, I forgot about stopping if the empty string is entered. To handle that, we can go back to your original recursion, but remembering to define what `questionnaire []` means.

```
questionnaire :: [String] -> IO [String]
questionnaire [] = return []
questionnaire (x:xs) = do
    putStr x
    (***) 
    user <- getLine
    case user of 
        "" -> return []
        _  -> do
            nextUser <- questionnaire xs
            return (user : nextUser)
```

Comment: Still so much to learn.... Nice and elegant solution. Answered.

Comment: ...but this does not have the early-exit-on-`""` behavior of the original.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oops, you're right, I forgot about that.

Comment: @chepner, practically I can catch the "" later before writing to sql, so will stick to answered.